# REGEX find specific substring if not part of the word

Tags: regex

I have troubles with simplifying regex which I created:

```
@"^sept$|[^a-zA-Z]sept[^a-zA-Z]]|[^a-zA-Z]sept$|^sept[^a-zA-Z]"
```

That regex has to find substring **sept**, which is not the part of any word (like september), I receive couple of different variations when word should be found, like:

sept

1sept

sept1

1sept1

sept

... etc.

In my patthern I search for sept which not start/end on letter(so it is not part of different word) and it can be on the start/end of the string. I checked functionality and it meets my needs, but I wonder if there is any better/simplier way to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tighten this up by using alternations for the boundary conditions:

```
(^|[^a-zA-Z])sept($|[^a-zA-Z])
```

But this would also potentially match one character one each side of `sept`.  To avoid this, you may use lookarounds, assuming your flavor of regex supports them:

```
(?<=^|[^a-zA-Z])sept(?=$|[^a-zA-Z])
```

Comment: Wow that's great example - in my approach I was just focus on matching specific cases and then I was replacing only 'sept' substring anyway with simple string.Replace (I'm not very familiar with regex). But thanks to second example I can do it immediately!

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-zA-z0-9]*(sept|SEPT)[a-zA-z0-9]*
```

Try above regex.